# React-Native undefined Unable to resolve module

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am trying to import a class I made in typescript, and initialize it to pass with my view components. But when I try to initialize the class, I get the following error:

[Error message in emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI40H.png)

My import looks like this:

```
import GameModel from 'src/Rematch/Models/GameModel';
```

My GameModel class looks like this:

```
import { QuestionModel } from "./QuestionModel";

export default class GameModel {

    public questions: QuestionModel[] = [];

    constructor(private id: number = 0) {
        this.getData(id);
    }

    getData(id: number) {
        console.log(id);
        this.questions.push(new QuestionModel(['Goed', 'Fout', 'Nog fouter'], 'Goed', 'Dit is de eerste vraag. Als je deze goed hebt krijg je punten'));
        this.questions.push(new QuestionModel(['Fout', 'Goed', 'Foutig'], 'Goed', 'Dit is de tweede vraag. Als je deze goed hebt krijg je punten'));
        this.questions.push(new QuestionModel(['Fout', 'Fouter dan fout', 'Goed'], 'Goed', 'Dit is de derde vraag. Als je deze goed hebt krijg je punten'));
        this.questions.push(new QuestionModel(['Dit is ook fout', 'Goed', 'Fout'], 'Goed', 'Dit is de vierde vraag. Als je deze goed hebt krijg je punten'))
    }
}
```

When typing:

```
const game: GameModel = new GameModel(1)
```

the error appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your import must be relative to the document where you write, thus should be something like this:

```
import GameModel from './Rematch/Models/GameModel';
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I don't understand why VS code autocompleted the import to be this way, but I know that I won't trust the autocomplete in the future. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. If you managed to make it work please accept my answer ;) Probably Vs code autocompleted the import because you can define with babel for instance module in order to call them as you have done (and avoid paths like ../../../../../)